# Nested table alignment in with percentage width

Tags: html, css, nested, html-table

Here I have nested formatted table. each table row head have a same equal width of the nested table column width. If I added any padding or margin the table cell getting collapse. How to make each of the columns in the same equal width with changing.

Here the code below:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="20%">Head1</th>
    <th width="20%">Head2</th>
    <th width="20%">Head3</th>
    <th width="20%">Head1</th>
    <th width="20%">Head2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>data1</td>
          <td>data2</td>
          <td>equa3</td>
          <td>data2</td>
          <td>equa3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=5 "><table>
       <tr>
        <td>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
       <td>equa3</td>
       <td>data2</td>
      <td>equa3</td>
     </tr>
  
     </table></td></tr>
     </table></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

Any suggestions:

Comment: You don't need a nested table, the nested table have the same number of columns than the primary table, so you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i want to add some text content of the each table content. if add any content the width of the table column will increase. i need equal width of the table column.

Comment: You have 5 columns in the main table and 5 columns in the nested table. **You don't need this nested table**, it has the same number of columns than the main table. That's what I said in first comment.

Comment: I added the code from jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/balajidev/fyahwqtg/ please check the code. in this code the columns are not aligned. i need to aligned columns

Comment: Impossible to help you. All your table have different column widths, very strange the way that, having the same number of columns, you are nesting tables. I insist, you don't need that nested table. Just add rows with the number of columns you need.

Comment: You cannot do such alignment by mixing percentage and pixel. Not only nested table, not possible even for div or other elements. At least the width of the outer table need to be pre-determined, or you will need to use javascript to calculate the pixel on the run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use This Type Of Structure why Because when records more that your expectation then you need Scrollbar .On that time your table structure not able to supports.I given One Structure just follow it its working fine in any environment ,But Finally According To Your Table Structure Its Not Possible .

```css
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
.header{
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
width:calc(100% - 17px);
width:-webkit-calc(100% - 17px);
width:-moz-calc(100% - 17px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="25">
    <th width="20%">Head1</th>
    <th width="20%">Head2</th>
    <th width="20%">Head3</th>
    <th width="20%">Head4</th>
    <th width="20%">Head5</th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:auto;">
<table width="100%">
  <tr height="50">
    <td width="20%"> </td>
    <td width="20%"> </td>
    <td width="20%"> </td>
    <td width="20%"> </td>
    <td width="20%"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="50">
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the with in your th field in the css this way both tables will share the same width attribute.

`td,th 
    {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 0;
        width: 20%;
    }`